# How to choose type based on uriParameter?

Tags: api, http, mule, raml

I have something like

```
/ticket:
    /{day}:
       uriParameters:
         day:
           enum:[mon,tue,wed]
           description: choose the day to buy ticket
```

How do I choose which schema to check based on which enum value my user chose?

I tried these but doesn't work.

```
type: !include <<day>>_schema.json
type: !include <<resourcePathName>>_schema.json
```

Thank you.